# Remove automatically injected script (likely browser hijacker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, greasemonkey, inject

So it seems I have a pesky browser hijacker that doesn't want to die. I've tried removing all extensions and reinstalling my browsers, however, every so often my clicks are redirected to some random ad-page. I've located a script which I believe is responsible by looking at the webpage source: it seems to place itself immediately after the head tag. I've tried using GreaseMonkey to remove the script (since its id is known) to no avail. I figure if I can remove (or prevent) this script my problem is solved. Any suggestions? Here's the HTML of the script:

`<script type="text/javascript" id="jc6202" ver="1.1.0.0" diu="WD-WCC3F74D435E647743C" fr="zl.sild" src="http://jackhopes.com/ext/zl.sild.js">`

(Note: I do not know what the src link is and can't advise clicking it!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because malware removal is not development

Comment: It's possible that your ISP or hacked router, or "free" VPN is doing this, but it's off topic here. Anyway, install something like *uBlock* and ban that domain.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Brock. I've installed uBlock and it works like a charm 8)

Comment: @BbJug, just beware that the opioid of uBlock does not remove the cancer of whatever has infected you.  It's just a stopgap/fallback.

Comment: O yes, uBlock is a God-send though I know the underlying problem is still here. At times my computer awakens itself at 4AM by an 'svchost.exe' process so I just assume my machine has fallen victim to some crypocurrency mining botnet ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Try to create a new browser profile. Many of such problems are solved in a clean profile. GM implies that your browser is FIrefox. Start from command line: `firefox -P` or `firefox -ProfileManager`. Create a new profile from the startup window and launch. If the problem has gone, you can delete your old one or you just move it to a backup folder on your disk. If you delete your profiles folder (in home folder) completely, a new profile will be be created automatically on next start. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: ... If the problem is not solved by the easy steps above or if other browsers have same issues, you have a serious problem on your system. Consider reinstalling your operating system from the scratch. Once the system is compromised on OS level, do not trust in it until next basic installation from the scratch even if antimalware tools tell you other. Do not use online banking or similar anymore before reinstallation.

Comment: Thanks for your concern@Quasimodo's clone. I ran firefox.exe -P and the javascript code was still injected into the browser. Do you have an specific idea what sort of abomination has infected me?